# how different hash is getting created for same data everytime?

Tags: python, django, django-models, hash, hash-function

I am adding hash of Account model object to one column of Account object. I am retrieving data from some target and creating Account object for that.Before saving object I am calculating hash of Account object and assigning to field hash_value. Then I am checking whether hash present in Account against hash_value field. To avoid unnecessary updation. But every time before insertion generated hash is different . Why?

I tried comparing each field in obj coming from target and Account present..those are same.

```py
# Account model
class Account(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    application_id = models.ForeignKey(Applications, related_name="account_application_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee_id = models.TextField(null=True)
    username = models.TextField(null=True)
    display_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    mail = models.TextField(null=True)
    department = models.TextField(null=True)
    company = models.TextField(null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    entitlements = models.TextField(null=True)
    hash_value = models.BigIntegerField(null=True)

    def __hash__(self):
        hash_sum_value = hash(
            (
                # self.uuid, no two uuid can be same
                str(self.application_id.uuid),  # include only uuid of application in hash
                str(self.employee_id),
                str(self.username),
                str(self.display_name),
                str(self.mail),
                str(self.department),
                str(self.company),
                str(self.description),
                str(self.entitlements)
            )
        )
        return hash_sum_value
```

```py
# checking hash present to avoid unnecessary updation.
obj = Account()
# some code to add values in obj
if entity_type == 'account':
    try:
        obj.hash_value = hash(obj)
    except TypeError:
        logging.info("Account info " + str(obj))
        logging.error("Unable to hash object: " + str(obj.username))

    if Account.objects.filter(hash_value=obj.hash_value).exists():
                # never comes here
        logging.info("Hash matched for acc " + obj.username)
        continue
```

I am expecting same hash for objects with same data.

Comment: Python's built-in `hash()` is not guaranteed to return values that are consistent beyond a single run of the interpreter - in fact, it's intentionally randomized to avoid some problems that can arise if an attacker can force hash collisions.  To get consistent, permanent hash values, use one of the algorithms in the `hashlib` standard module.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper tried with md5 of hashlib . Its working fine now.